# Android AdMob failing to initialize with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController

Tags: android, admob

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
}
```

And the error message I am getting is:

```
I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uO>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
    at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:151)
    ...
```

I can post more if needed.
My `minSdkVersion` is 21 and my target and compile version is 28.
That error happens when I initialize MobileAds like this:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

Android Studio kept telling me that various support packages needed to be the same level as the `targetSdkVersion` so I kept overriding them in the dependencies section until I no longer got gradle warnings, but I still get this error now. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?